# Can I initialise the size(both row and col) of a vector of vectors in the function declaration in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

For example:

```
void fillVector(std::vector<<std::vector<int> >& grid(int row, std::vector<int(int col));

int main(){

    std::vector<<std::vector<int> > grid(4, std::vector,int>(2));
    fillVector(grid);

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a possibility or am I completely off the mark?

Comment: No, the vector has whatever size it has as a runtime property. However if you use std::array, the size is part of the type, and you can specify that in the declaration.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A function call initialises the parameter. You can then use `grid.size()` and `grid[0].size()` in the function to get rows and columns. Note that a vector of vectors can be jagged (i.e. different rows can have different size).

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` is used when you don't know the sizes at compile time. When you do, use std::array instead:

```
void fillArray(std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4>& grid);

int main(){

    std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 4> grid={}; //initialize with zeros, like vector default constructor
    fillArray(grid);

    return 0;
}
```

Another advantage of `std::array` is that it does not use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Your angle brackets do not match.

Comment: @Eric. Thank you.  Fixed.